# getting Value of type 'Infragistics.Documents.Excel.Workbook' cannot be converted to 'Infragistics.Excel.Workbook'

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

How can i fix this error at gridExporter.Export(exportGrid, filePath)

Value of type 'Infragistics.Documents.Excel.Workbook' cannot be converted to 'Infragistics.Excel.Workbook'.

```
 Dim excelWorkbook As New Infragistics.Excel.Workbook
            Try
                excelWorkbook = gridExporter.Export(exportGrid, filePath)


                Dim worksheet As Infragistics.Excel.Worksheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets(0)
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Infragistics, but the error message appears to be telling you that `gridExporter.Export(exportGrid, filePath)` returns an object of type `Infragistics.Documents.Excel.Workbook`, but you are trying to store in in a variable that you declared as type `Infragistics.Excel.Workbook`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you have one of the following two scenarios:

- Multiple versions of the Excel assembly are referenced where one before 2011 Volume 1 and the other is 2011 Volume 1 or later.
- You have recently upgraded the Infragistics controls in your application from before 2011 Volume 1 to 2011 Volume 1 or newer.

If you have duplicate references you will need to remove the one that you don't want.  If you recently upgraded your application, the Infragistics.Excel namespace changed to Infragistics.Documents.Excel in NetAdvantage 2011 Volume 1.  All of the namespace changes for the Excel and Documents assemblies are in the [online documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/?page=Win_Breaking_Changes_in_2011_Volume_1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to set the workbook equal to an export? If you are using the UltraGridExcelExporter you don't use any sort of return type, it just runs and exports. You can see some samples here... [Export Grid Data to Excel](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/WinGridExcelExporter_Export_Grid_Data_To_Excel.html) and also [Create a Workbook](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/jQuery/2012.1/CLR4.0/HTML/ExcelEngine_Create_a_Workbook.html)